# Django: Changing a model after passing it in context

Tags: django

I am changing a list of field's values upon viewing, but I want to pass the unchanged values to the context. The case here is of a primitive notification system where upon viewing the notification, it should change its status to viewed.

views.py

```
class Notification(TemplateView):

template_name='myapp/notification.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    user = self.request.user
    user_unread = user.notification_set.filter(viewed=False)
    user_read = user.notification_set.filter(viewed=True)
    context = super(Notification, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'user_unread': user_unread, 'user_read': user_read})
    for msg in user_unread:
        msg.viewed = True
        msg.save()
    return context
```

The Problem with this code however, is that I am getting duplicated values in the read and unread lists, even though I have saved the new values to the model after updating the context that is passed to the template.

template:

```
Unread: 
<ul>
{% for msg in user_unread %}
    <li> {{ msg }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

Already read: 

<ul>
{% for msg in user_read %}
    <li> {{ msg }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

On a sidenote, I am new to CBVs and if there if my view code above could be improved I'd love some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the lazy nature of querysets. A queryset does not actually touch the database until you evaluate it, which usually occurs when you iterate. So in your code, you iterate through `user_unread` in the view, to set the read status: so the contents of the queryset are fixed at that point. But you don't iterate through `user_read` until you reach the template, so the query is not made until then, *after* you have updated all the unread notifications.

The way to fix this is to explicitly evaluate the read queryset in the view, before you update the unread ones. You can do this by simply calling `list` on it:

```
context.update({'user_unread': user_unread, 'user_read': list(user_read)})
for msg in user_unread:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting another duplicate query set to update the objects. Use non-updated for template context and update only another one.

Like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    user = self.request.user
    user_unread = user.notification_set.filter(viewed=False)

    #Do some operation on qs so that it gets evaluated, like
    nitems = len(user_unread)

    #get another queryset to update
    user_unread_toupdate = user.notification_set.filter(viewed=False)

    user_read = user.notification_set.filter(viewed=True)
    context = super(Notification, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'user_unread': user_unread, 'user_read': user_read})

    #Use 2nd queryset
    for msg in user_unread_toupdate:
        msg.viewed = True
        msg.save()
    return context
```

Django would cache for each queryset differently. So once evaluated `user_unread` will have its own copy of objects.

Although, its not very elegant/efficient as multiple copies of similar queryset are loaded, so if number of records high, it will be slower.

Comment: No, this will not work, for exactly the same reason: the querysets are not evaluated until after the updates have been made, so the messages will always show as read.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Have mentioned that and evaluated the QS `len(user_unread)` so that it gets evaluated, just after getting it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see that.